# Reading the file '/proc/cpuinfo' and using 'cat /proc/cpuinfo' in ADB shell are returning different values

Tags: android, linux, shell

I'm trying to get CPU info from both an Intel and Android cpu devices. I'm running this in code:

```
Process process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/cpuinfo");
```

Then reading the output line by line. The strange thing is this is showing ARM info, eg:

```
Processor   : ARMv7 processor rev 1 (v7l)
```

This also happens when you plainly read the file from IO.

Now when I run 'cat /proc/cpuinfo' through the ADB shell, all the correct information relating to an Intel proc is there.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: What happens if you run 'uname -r'?  Or 'uname -a'?  Are any of these tests run on an emulator (just curious)?

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing - if I `adb shell cat proc/cpuinfo`, I get the full readout that you'd expect, including 'model name' that specifies the intel processor and clock speed - but if I try read that file from an AIR app on my device, I get the 'armv7' info.

Comment: I was considering submitting here asking about it, but I think your question already covers it - too bad there haven't been any answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue at my device(DELL tablet).

At first, It crashed when my app load libs(armeabi-v7a), and then I found that its architecture is not arm but x86.

So I build the libs of x86 and I want to recognize the architecture of device in code to decide which libs(arm or x86) should be loaded.

The result always is arm not x86 !!

Maybe it run the something like simulator to change type under background because the other libs still is amr type.

At finally, I make a x86 folder in libs and build all libs(x86),

and then it can run successfully and get the right info from "/proc/cpuinfo" by itself.